# С чего начать при изучении SQL в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

Хочу научиться работать с SQL в python. С чего начать?

1. Нужно ли скачать phpMyAdmin?
2. Нужно ли скачать MySQL?
3. Какую библиотеку использовать mysql или PyMySQL?

Comment: ну все зависит какую субд вы будете использовать

Comment: 1)не нужно 2)естественно 3)pymysql (мне кажется по ней больше туториалов, а так на ваше усмотрение) . А вообще если нет опыта работы с *sql*, то лучше сначала просто с ней научиться работать, потом брать питон

Comment: 1. Программа phpMyAdmin - это один из способов подключаться к MySQL из браузера, к примеру на сервере и не самый удобный вариант. Ему есть множество альтернатив в том числе desktop: https://freshdesignweb.com/mysql-client/ 2. Надо установить MySQL и научиться к нему подключаться из вышеупомянутых программ. 2a. Можно просто поставить OpenServer и все будет в коробке и готово к употреблению без лишних телодвижений (на php не обращаем внимания). 2b. Вам может понадобится какая-нибудь тестовая БД, чтобы руками не набивать данные с нуля: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так вы хотите научиться языку SQL или использованию баз данных в Питоне?

Если первое, то возьмите какой-нибудь учебник по SQL, учите теорию, конструкции, решайте задачи. Можно установить MySQL, можно использовать SQLite из Питона, можно учиться даже в браузере с SQLFiddle. И хорошенько усвойте термины: [СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), [БД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), [SQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), [MySQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) и прочее, что встретится.

Материалы по SQL:

- [W3Schools (eng)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)
- [SchoolsW3 (рус)](https://schoolsw3.com/sql/index.php)
- [Серия уроков на ITProger](https://itproger.com/course/sql)
- [Ещё серия уроков](http://moonexcel.com.ua/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-sql1-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_ru)
- [Запуск SQL в браузере](http://sqlfiddle.com)
- И много чего ещё найти можно

Кстати, если целитесь на MySQL, то научитесь работать с консольным клиентом этой СУБД – [документация здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

---

Если Вы это уже более-менее освоили и хотите научиться использовать базы данных из Python, то вот есть 2 варианта, через свой SQL и DB-API или посредством ORM:

**1. DB-API:**

- [Хабр: Python, работа с базой данных](https://habr.com/ru/post/321510/)
- [Официальная документация SQLite (eng)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

**2. ORM** – [Object-Relational Mapping](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM):

- Peewee [peewee](/questions/tagged/peewee):

  - [Хабр: Python, используем ORM](https://habr.com/en/post/322086/)
- SQLAlchemy [sqlalchemy](/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy):

  - [Официальная документация SQLAlchemy (eng)](https://www.sqlalchemy.org)
  - [ВикиУчебник: SQLAlchemy](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy)
- Есть ещё Django-ORM, но это только если весь [django](/questions/tagged/django) собираетесь изучать.